# Is there an easy way to export Journey Logic?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I am looking for a documentation about the latest journeys and decision splits that I need to share with a wider organization. Is there an easy way to export entry, exit and journey logic?

Hoping there is a canned feature to export logic and steps.

Comment: Nope.  All data is associated to event transactions like 'sent', 'open', 'click' and doesn't account for contact/data filters, splits and waits.

Comment: Would you be keen on using API to export the journey configurations in a JSON data format?

Comment: @BradSapkota - assuming the API to export would include all decision splits and wait steps, that would work for me.  Yes please.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve journey configuration using the REST API in a JSON response. For this purpose you'd need a REST API client, [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) is good as gold for API testing.

You'd then use the `Get Journey` REST request under Interactions in the developer [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionById.htm).

Once you've right API access then you'd need the journey ID that you can find once on the address bar of the browser once you enter the desired journey.

Screenshot Reference:
[image]

Here is the sample payload:

```
GET /interaction/v1/interactions/{{Id}} HTTP/1.1
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{access token}}
```

Sample Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
{
    "id": "00a0a000-9988-e111-9ef0-88aaa9dddaa0",
    "key": "journey_key",
    "name": "Welcome email series",
    "description": "This welcome email journey contains an entry event, goal, activities, and tags",
    "version": 1,
    "workflowApiVersion": 1,
    "createdDate": "2014-06-17T10:29:43.673",
    "modifiedDate": "2014-06-17T11:53:22.477",
    "triggers": [
        {
            "key": "first-activity",
            "name": "First activity. The starting point.",
            "type": "ContactDecision",
            "eventDefinitionKey": "my-entry-event-key",
            "arguments": {
                "criteria": "<filterXML"
            }
        }
    ],
    "goals": [
        {
            "name": "My Goal",
            "key": "goal-1",
            "type": "ContactDecision",
            "description": "This is my goal description.",
            "arguments": {
                "criteria": "<filterXML>"
            }
        }
    ],
    "activities": [
        {
            "id": "11b1b111-9988-e111-9ef0-88aaa9dddbb1",
            "key": "send-welcome-email",
            "name": "Welcome email",
            "type": "Email",
            "outcomes": [
                {
                    "key": "sent-welcome-email-then-random-split",
                    "next": "random-split"
                }
            ],
            "arguments": {
                "emailToSend": "394911",
                "emailAddress": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "22c2c222-9988-e111-9ef0-88aaa9dddcc2",
            "key": "random-split",
            "name": "Random split",
            "type": "RandomSplit",
            "outcomes": [
                {
                    "key": "random-split-then-send-sms",
                    "next": "send-sms",
                    "arguments": {
                        "percentage": 90
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "random-split-then-10-percent-end",
                    "next": "send-sms2",
                    "arguments": {
                        "percentage": 10
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "tags": [
        {"name": "Fun Run"},
        {"name": "5K"}
    ],
    "status": "Draft",
    "definitionId": "33d3d333-9988-e111-9ef0-88aaa9eeedd3"
}
```